# Как я могу выводить переменные в последних действиях админки с красивыми названиями?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-model

[image: Фото админки]

Мне надо чтобы в `my actions` `IssuesNumberChange` отображалось не как `object (....) а`, как `IssuesNumberChange.publications`. Как я могу это сделать?

`models.py`:

```
class IssuesNumberChange(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    volume_of_implement = models.SmallIntegerField()
    new_number_of_issues = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Issues Number Change"
        verbose_name_plural = "Issues Number Changes"
```

`admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(models.IssuesNumberChange)
class IssuesNumberChangeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['publication', 'volume_of_implement', 'new_number_of_issues']
```

`код от модели Publication`:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    acronym = models.CharField(max_length=31, unique=True)
    publication_type = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=choices.PUBLICATION_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default=0,
    )
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    repec_institution_handle = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    repec_series_handle = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    repec_series_provider_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    next_submission_number = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    # TODO: Ask about this, looks like NGINX proxy is required
    # public_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    issn = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    number = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="The number assigned to this journal",
    )
    starting_volume = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    allow_supplemental = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # changed to true because of the publication posted inactive
    referee_guidelines = models.FileField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d/")
    associate_editor_guidelines = models.FileField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d/")
    reviewing_editor_guidelines = models.FileField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d/")
    final_draft_guidelines = models.FileField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d/")
    mission_statement = models.FileField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d/")
    # TODO: WYSIWYG
    submission_instructions = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # TODO: WYSIWYG
    copyright = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # TODO: WYSIWYG
    supplemental_policy = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Publication"
        verbose_name_plural = "Publications"

    def _add_default_jel_categories(self):
        count = 0
        for category in choices.JEL_DEFAULT_CHOICES:
            JELCategory.objects.create(
                publication=self,
                key=choices.JEL_KEY_CHOICES[count][0],
                label=str(category[1]),
            )
            count += 1

    def _create_default_settings(self):
        EmailSettings.objects.create(publication=self)
        DisplaySettings.objects.create(publication=self)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Publication, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            self.displaysettings
        except AttributeError:
            self._add_default_jel_categories()
            self._create_default_settings()

    @property
    def webmaster(self):
        return self.actor_set.filter(role__role_type=0).first()

    @property
    def roles(self):
        return self.role_set.exclude(role_type=0)

    @property
    def latest_volume(self):
        return self.volume_set.latest("number")

    def set_starting_volume(self, num):
        self.starting_volume = num

    def get_publication_type(self):
        return choices.PUBLICATION_TYPE_CHOICES[self.publication_type][1]

    get_publication_type.short_description = "Type"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам в `models` нужно добавить:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.publication
```

Полностью ваша модель должна выглядеть так:

```
class IssuesNumberChange(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    volume_of_implement = models.SmallIntegerField()
    new_number_of_issues = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.publication

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Issues Number Change"
        verbose_name_plural = "Issues Number Changes"
```

*Если ответ помог, вы можете отменить его как правильный, это поможет другим.*

Comment: Не-а, уже пробовал, к сожалению почему-то не работает

Comment: понял, добавьте в вопрос код от модели `Publication` и я напишу вам правильный ответ.

Comment: Добавил код от модели Publication, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Вам нужно `IssuesNumberChange.publications`? Попробуйте в `__str__` прописать так: `return f'{self.id}.{self.publication}'` ну или вместо `id` можно подставить `volume_of_implement` если нужно.

Comment: Тоже не помогло. Сейчас я пробую это осуществить через html страничку админки. Пока что получается только как-то переименовать `IssuesNumberChange object (......)`, но не подставить вместо этого `IssuesNumberChange.publications`

Comment: Да, вы всё-таки были правы, это помогло. Просто почему-то надо было пересоздавать `IssuesNumberChange`. Спасибо вам за помощь